# Can monoids of "continuous words" be realized as initial monoid objects?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ct.category-theory, real-analysis, monoidal-categories, semigroups-and-monoids

Whenever $X$ is a set, write $X^*$ for the monoid freely generated by $X$. The elements of $X$ are, of course, words in the letters $X$. When $X$ is finite, there also seems to be a great many sensible notions of continuous words in $X$. For instance, we could define that a continuous word in $X$ is a piecewise-linear curve $\gamma : [0,T] \rightarrow [0,\infty)^X$ satisfying $\gamma(0)=0$, such that each $\gamma_x : [0,T] \rightarrow [0,\infty)$ has non-negative derivative and such that $$\sum_{x \in X} (\gamma_x)'(t) = 1$$ for all $t \in (0,T)$. And this could be weakened considerably by replacing piecewise linear with piecewise differentiable, for example. In both cases, we get a monoid by concatenation of paths, and in both cases, $X^*$ can be embedded rather naturally in this monoid.

What I'd like to know is whether these kinds of monoids can be defined, in a non-artificial way, as initial objects in the category of monoids of an appropriately chosen monoidal category.

Comment: No topology on $X$ or $X^{*}$? Then you're just getting a bunch of paths in $[0, \infty)$, aren't you?

Comment: @AndrejBauer, my apologies, there was meant to be a condition $\gamma(0)=0$ in there. Yes, these are monoids of paths; if $X$ has two elements, call them north and east, then the constraints tell us that we're always moving either north or east, never south or west, and that we're moving with a constant "speed" in an appropriate sense.